# Clio 2001 stereo question

Tags: audio, renault, clio, connector

I've recently purchased a Clio from a friend, but I need to replace the stereo in it. I've been given an old Kenwood stereo to replace the original stereo with so I can stick my aux cable into the machine and play some decent music, but I'm not 100% sure what extra cables I need so I can have both the new stereo and the remote by the steering wheel working.

I understand from the model of stereo and a bit of tinkering and investigating that I need at least the 16 pin kenwood adaptor - [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/GENUINE-Kenwood-car-stereo-radio-CD-player-wiring-loom-16-Pin-adaptor-KDC-KRC-/371150576513?hash=item566a4c5b81:g:WV4AAOSwdpxUU2al) seems to be ideal.

Ideally, I'd like to keep the controls on the stalk working - will I need to buy a separate loom for this (like [this one](http://www.dynamicsounds.co.uk/autoleads-pc99-x12-renault-clio-laguna-kangoo-safrane-twingo-stalk-adaptor.html)) or is there a patch cable or adaptor I can buy which will fit between the above adaptor and the existing plug?

It seems like a lot of extra wiring to cram into what appears to be a small space!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As supplied the Kenwood unit will have included a loom the same as [this one](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/GENUINE-Kenwood-car-stereo-radio-CD-player-wiring-loom-16-Pin-adaptor-KDC-KRC-/371150576513?hash=item566a4c5b81:g:WV4AAOSwdpxUU2al) (from your question).  If the unit no longer had this loom with it, I'm afraid you will need to buy another.  The end which fits in the stereo is Kenwood specific but the other end (that plugs into the car) is an [ISO](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:ISO_10487_connector_pinout.svg) standard connector.  Sadly the ISO standard does not include pins to cater for volume or skip controls which your steering wheel will have.

There is sadly no standard for these controls so each car marker has, sadly, done something slightly different.  Somebody appears to have reverse engineered the Renault system and publish the pinouts [here](http://tlcdcemu.sourceforge.net/hardware.html).  If you are good with electronics you could probably engineer your own patch lead.  The problem is though, the connectors.  The simplest way to get ahold of all of the connectors required to manufacture your own patch lead is sadly to buy the patch lead you have identified in your other [link](https://www.dynamicsounds.co.uk/autoleads-pc99-x12-renault-clio-laguna-kangoo-safrane-twingo-stalk-adaptor.html).

You don't actually need the steering wheel controls for the head unit to work but if you wish to retain the steering wheel functionality, you will need this additional wiring.

As an alternative, Kenwood do offer a range of their own remotes which you can stick to your wheel that communicate via infrared such as [this one](http://www.adriangame.co.uk/kenwremote.html).  You may find one of these a cheaper option that purchasing the additional loom.  It would however leave the original Renault controls on your wheel in place and useless.

As regards space for the looms, you will usually find there is more space than you might imagine behind the dashboard in which you can hide bits of loom.

Answer (score 2):

Just to post a follow up, the adaptor for both got the job done :) my kenwood stereo now fits perfectly and works like a charm.